# Deleting and then adding a new identical entity throws an error

Tags: breeze

I have a model called a DeviceAccount. It is a join table that allows me to create many to many relationships.

I have a function that creates a new DeviceAccount by handing it an account & a device to join. See here:

```
var createDeviceAccount = function (account, device) {
        var initialValues = {
            account: account,
            device: device
        };
        return manager.createEntity(entityNames.deviceAccount, initialValues);
    };
```

I have a function to delete a DeviceAccount. See here:

```
var deleteDeviceAccount = function (account, device) {
        var baseQuery = entityQuery.from('DeviceAccounts');
        var p1 = new breeze.Predicate('device', 'eq', device);
        var p2 = new breeze.Predicate("account", "eq", account);
        var modQuery = baseQuery.where(p1.and(p2));
        var results = manager.executeQueryLocally(modQuery);
        results[0].entityAspect.setDeleted();
    };
```

If I locally create, remove, create, remove the same device/account pair there is no problem.
If I take a device/account pair that exists on the server I can remove it fine, but when I add it again I recieve the following error:

> Uncaught Error: This key is already attached:
>   DeviceAccount:#Test.Models-5:::5

If I follow this in more depth I can see that removing a local device changes the entityState to be 'Detached' and if I remove a device that also exists on the server its entityState gets changed to be 'Deleted'. I can't follow much further than this and I was hoping someone could explain why this could be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to be clear, **deleting** an entity via entityAspect.setDeleted causes its entityState to be set to "Deleted".  This action marks the entity for deletion on the next save and also removes it from any navigation collections on the client.  The entity is still being tracked by the EntityManager after this operation.

In contrast, **detaching** an entity via entityAspect.setDetached removes it from the entityManager cache completely.  This also removes the entity from any navigation collections on the client, but will have NO effect on the server during an EntityManager.saveChanges call, because the EntityManager no longer "knows" about the entity.  Think of "detaching" as telling the EntityManager to completely forget about an entity, as if it had never been queried in the first place.

"Deleting" an entity followed by "re-adding" the same entity is problematic because this would cause the EntityManager to have two incarnations of the same entity; a deleted version and an added version.  Therefore the EntityManager throws the exception that you are seeing.

I think what you want to do is delete and add a "new" clone entity with a different id.

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm still a bit confused about something...
AFAIK when I am running that CreateDeviceAccount function it should create a whole new entity with a unique ID but for some reason it is assuming the ID of the old Entity. I'm not sure why this is happening? Is it because something in Breeze detects that all the properties match the old entity (that is marked for deletion) and therefore wont create a new one?

Comment: Only the fields defined as being part of the key are used to determine "uniqueness". What does your entity creation code look like? What does the metadata for this entityType look like.

Comment: Thanks! I found the issue. My primary key was generated from the Account&Device properties. Changing it to be unique generated property fixed the problem. I got convinced the issue was in the javascript and didn't even think of checking the database.

Comment: @JayTraband - are there guidelines for the following scenario? In Angular components, the Breeze entity manager tracks changes, e.g. createEntity() when they do Add. But imagine if they click Cancel from that Add screen and now go to a different Component. Well, the Breeze manager still is tracking that createEntity, so next time commit() is called, it's trying to add it! It can only be resolved if the user refreshes the screen. Are there guidelines for making sure the state manager forgets pending changes when the user goes to a different component?

Answer (score 2):

The reason this happens is that Breeze is keeping track of that entity until you have fully removed it from the server to keep you from creating a new entity with the same ID, which of course will throw a server exception since you can't do that.

If you called saveChanges() on your entityManager before you tried to recreate it, then Breeze will go out to the server, remove the entity from the DB, return the promise, and completely detach the entity from the local cache since it no longer exists on the server.

You could set the entityState to detached manually, but then if you try to saveChanges and that ID already exists on the server it will throw an error.

#### Best Option

Pass the entity into the saveChanges method in an array -

```
results[0].entityAspect.setDeleted();
manager.saveChanges([results[0]]).then(saveSucceeded);

function saveSucceeded() {
    console.log('Entity removed from server');
}
```

Now after saveSucceeded has completed you can create a new entity with that ID

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I believe your solution would work however it doesn't seem ideal to me. I am not adding the same Entity I am adding a new entity that just so happens to have the same properties (except for id) but when I try to create this new entity it gets given the same ID as the old one and throws this error?...

This means when I do a saveChanges I would expect it to delete the old entity, add a new one with the same Device & Account properties but a new unique ID.